# Freshly created Hyper-V images (linux and win11) disappeared after first shutdown

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I used the Hyper-V Quick create tool, to create a win11 dev image.
(it was offered automatically by the app).
After downloading, it installed automatically,
and the Win11 image automatically opened and ran fast and flawless.

After shutting it down, I though I would find it under Hyper-V manager,
but nope nothing is visible there.

I tried to look for images manually, but neither under Documents\Virtual Machnies nor under ProgramData\Microsoft could I find anything.

I used search for .VHD or .VHDX, but nothing found.
Same happened with a linux creation.

Is it possible that the VM-s were only created for a single run, and were deleted after the first shutdown?

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: No, the VMs (that are offered) are permanent VMs once set up. I would suggest you pressed the Delete button by mistake...

Comment: You might not find the well-hidden machines the way you searched.  Open Hyper-V manager, top left: are the machines there?  If not, as posted you may have deleted instead of just turning them off. I use Hyper-V.

Comment: No, I don't think deletion is the case. I have an interesting theory. This is my company powerhouse laptop, where unfortunately installations are bound to admin rights. I intalled the VM-s  from my account while having an admin assist me via TeamViewer with the admin PW. The assumption is that the images are then somehow getting stored in an admin folder that is not visible to my account. I hope if he logs in to his admin account he can locate the files and we can copy and run it on my side also, without his pw needed before each run, that would ruin the xp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that was the case roughly:
This feature does not like a company setup with administrators.
There were some awkward, sloppy workarounds, but eventually decided to move this functionality to a separate, clean machine, that is not company governed.